# Spring Data JPA - Hibernate - OneToMany, ManytoOne bidirectional

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Have 2 Entities: Orders and Products. 1 Order can have Many Products and Many Products can belong to 1 Order (Each Product only belongs to 1 Order).

With unidirectional association at Order Entity, I am able to retrieve product details when performing orderRepo.findAll(); In similar fashion, need order details when performing productRepo.findAll();

Tried code:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class OrderData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long orderId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "customer_name", nullable = false)
    private String customerName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ProductData> products;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_details")
public class ProductData {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "product_name", nullable = false)
    private String productName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    private OrderData orderData;
}
```

While inserting at products; we are getting error: **"insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint jpa"**

While performing productRep.findAll(): **infinite loop for hibernate select queries**

Tried @JsonIgnore. This not returning child or parent elements.
Tried @JsonManagedReference vs @JsonBackReference - still no luck.

Please guide me on this

Comment: Do you bind any Order instance, which is present in the database, to the new Product? You declared the OrderData field as non-nullable, so you have to pass an object there.

Comment: updated code with nullable=true; able to insert elements still while productRepo.findAll() prints infinite hibernate select calls in ide console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mappedBy attribute points to the wrong field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "productId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ProductData> products;
```

This must be the back reference:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderData", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ProductData> products;
```